# Concatenate large dataset from multiple worksheets of a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, concatenation

I'm using the code below to concatenate certain sheets in my file into a sheet named "Master".

1. Currently, my script duplicates the header row, but I would like to prevent this. The data in all the sheets is in exactly the same format with the same header.
2. Each sheet has 58 columns and one of the sheets has 5000 rows.
3. Ideally I'd like the script to overwrite the "Master" sheet each time the script is run.

How can I modify my script to accomplish these goals?

```
function concatAllSheets()
{
  var includedSheet = ['Virtue data - Norway - NOK', 'Virtue data - Sweden - SKK', 'Virtue data - Denmark - DKK', 'Virtue Data - GBP', 'Virtue data - EUR markets', 'Virtue data - Arabia - USD'];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheetName = 'Master'
  var mother = ss.insertSheet(sheetName);
  for(var i = 0; i < allSheets.length; i++)
  {
    var sht = allSheets[i];
    if(includedSheet.indexOf(sht.getName()) > -1)
    {
      var rng = sht.getDataRange();
      var rngA = rng.getValues();
      for(var j = 0; j < rngA.length; j++)
      {
        var row = rngA[j];
        mother.appendRow(row);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than calling `appendRow()` for each row of data, which will really slow your script down, use a [batch operation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) like [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

To do so, create an `allData` array to hold what will be the content of your "Master" sheet. As you iterate through the sheets, append their data into `allData`, and finally print it to the sheet.

As you're iterating, you can do a simple check of `allData`'s length, to see if the header row is already there. If `allData` is empty, then there is obviously no header row.

```
function concatAllSheets()
{
  var includedSheet=['Virtue data - Norway - NOK','Virtue data - Sweden - SKK','Virtue data - Denmark - DKK','Virtue Data - GBP','Virtue data - EUR markets','Virtue data - Arabia - USD'];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  var sheetName='Master'
  var mother=ss.insertSheet(sheetName);
  var allData = [];
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
  {
    var sht=allSheets[i];
    if(includedSheet.indexOf(sht.getName())>-1)
    {
      var rng=sht.getDataRange();
      var rngA=rng.getValues();
      if (allData.length == 0) // This will only ever be true on the first sheet copied
      {
        allData = rngA;
      } else {
        rngA.shift(); // Remove the first row
        allData = allData.concat(rngA);
      }
    }
  }
  mother.getRange(1, 1, allData.length, allData[0].length).setValues(allData); // Use a batch operation to insert the data
}
```

Comment: thanks - but how would i keep the first row from the first sheet? so that i maintain a header row.

Comment: And can i set the script to overwrite the existing data in the master sheet if it already exists? so the script could start pasting data from row2 as i would already have the header row in this file

Comment: i also got the error - "Exceeded maximum execution time"

Comment: @Nij Try this revision and see if your maximum execution time error persists.

Comment: seems to have worked - will check and let you know if i have an issue - thank you!

Comment: Oh - what about replacing the data in the  "master" sheet ..ie delete data in there first? upto col BF only

Comment: @Nij I hope it does! You can use any of the [`clear()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear) methods on a range. If you're having trouble with that, feel free to post another question.

Comment: thanks. Pls see the comment below re batch reads etc - should  i update?

Comment: @Nij Which comment below? The code I posted is using batch operations.

Comment: @Nij It's basically the same thing written in two different styles.

Comment: so how can i amend the query to update the existing master sheet (usually more rows but should delete data first)...but i want to add formulas from col BG onwards which i'd like to keep when the data is being repulled. so what do you suggest?                   OR should the query add formulas from another sheet into this master sheet? welcome to suggestions... thanks

Comment: @Nij I'd suggest looking at your `getRange()` options to select just the data you want, copy that, and then add formulas. Given that this is a new topic, please take that hint, see what you can come up with, and post another question if you have any issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the size of the dataset, you need to minimize reads and writes by using the batch methods [`Range#getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [`Range#setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues). You can also avoid iterating over the unnecessary sheets by only binding the ones in your array of names, using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). This pattern also ensures that you collect all the data you intend - if there is a typo in your names array, or the sheet's name is changed unintentionally, this will throw an exception rather than silently not including the data.

```
function concatenateSheets() {
  var sheetNames = ["name1", "name2", ...];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dest = ss.getSheetByName("someName");
  var output = [], header = [];
  // Assemble a single paste output from all the sheets.
  sheetNames.forEach(function (name) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    if(!sheet)
      throw new Error("Incorrect sheet name '" + name + "'");
    var vals = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    // Remove the header row. 
    header = vals.splice(0, 1);
    // Append to existing output array.
    output = [].concat(output, vals);
  });
  // Serialize output data array.
  if(dest && output.length && output[0].length) {
    // Remove all existing data values on the destination sheet.
    // (Only necessary if the number of rows or columns can decrease.)
    dest.getDataRange().clearContent();

    // Prepend the header on the output data array.
    output.unshift(header);

    dest.getRange(1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
  }
}
```